# How to pass a created object from a controller (.ascx) to a page (.aspx)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, ascx

I have a normal asp.net web form page (.aspx) that includes a map, and when you click a link "Add marker", it hits some JQuery that loads/shows the popup dialog (.ascx) on top of the page.

On this dialog, I'm then prompted to add a Name, co-ordinates, etc. Once I hit "Submit", in the .ascx.cs (c# file), it creates a new MapLocation object given the data you type in.

However, what I then need to be able to do, is to somehow pass that newly created MapLocation object (created in the .ascx) back to the web page (.aspx) so that I can add it to a List in the page (aspx.cs). From there I can then continuously add new locations through the dialog and tally them in the page.

I hope this is simple and I am being stupid, as I've been pulling my hair out for the past two days - I don't really want to hit the database each time I submit a location which is my only other option at the minute.

Here is the code structure for the pages involved, if it makes a difference:

```
-map
  -webform.aspx
-controls
  -popup.ascx
```

Thanks for any help!
FYP

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective, the MapLocation object should be stored in a System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState key and test on ASPX page if the session request comes from it.

[ASCX.cs]

```
MapLocation user = new MapLocation();

// MapLocation property settings goes here

// Store MapLocation object on Session
Session["YourSession"] = user;
```

[ASPX.cs]

```
MapLocation location = Session["YourSession"] as MapLocation;

// create a list based on the object
List<MapLocation> list = new List<MapLocation>();
list.Add(location);
```

Hopefully this is useful for you.